Can data be of persistence by just call context's method 'insert'?
I was trying to get data generated can be reload after App restarts. The method is insert of environment object 'modelContext'.
@Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
the data is an array and expected to be fetched by @Query, a list view iterates the array to show elements within.
@Query(sort:\GroceryItem.name) private var  grocery:[GroceryItem]
new element is added somewhere in a button's press event handler like
context.insert(GroceryItem(name: "Washing Powder", check_off:false))
once I start App and press the button, new element is put into array and list view get new element showing up.
when I restart the app, the list view is blank without item added just now.
I assume App can reload item added previously and put it into list view whereas list is empty.
As I am told by Apple official tutorial, context's insert method is the way App keep data persistent and it seems data is transient.
below is my code snippet.
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Query(sort: \Friend.name) private var friends: [Friend]
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var context
    
    @State private var newName = ""
    @State private var newDate = Date.now
    @State private var newNote = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List(friends) { friend in
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    HStack {
                        if friend.isBirthdayToday {
                            Image(systemName: "birthday.cake")
                        }
                        Text(friend.name)
                            .bold(friend.isBirthdayToday)
                        Spacer()
                        Text(friend.birthday, format: .dateTime.month(.wide).day().year())
                    }
                    if friend.isBirthdayToday {
                        Text(friend.note)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Birthdays")
            .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
                    Text("New Birthday")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .padding()
                    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                        DatePicker(selection:$newDate, in: Date.distantPast...Date.now, displayedComponents: .date) {
                            TextField("Name", text: $newName)
                                .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            
                        }
                        TextField("Note", text: $newNote)
                            .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                            
                    }
                    Button("Save") {
                        let newFriend = Friend(name: newName, birthday: newDate, note: newNote)

                        context.insert(newFriend) //here i add new friend.
    
                        newName = ""
                        newDate = .now
                        newNote = ""
                    }
                    .bold()
                }
                .padding()
                .background(.bar)
            }
        
    }
}



Be sure to suspend the app like a user would do before you click restart, i.e. swipe it up and go back to home screen. That is required for it to save all the changes.
